# Send message using MAC address on PC without IP in LAN

Tags: c, linux, networking

Need to send messages on PC without configured IP using MAC address in C language as a reply on PC's broadcast message. I suppose I should work with ethernet-header and use some (linux) kernel's structures and subroutines, however I couldn't find good links and samples about my question.

Comment: read about raw sockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of sending a raw Ethernet frame in Linux:

https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/1922600

Comment: And receive side: https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/2862515